# Why BufferedImage is not working well?!! Is it because I misused it?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, bufferedimage, grayscale

I want to copy a gray image using `BufferedImage` from `getRGB()` to `int[][]` and then to `setRGB()`. The problem is that the size of image is different from the size of the one that the program outputs it. The original image has file size = 176 KB, whereas the output image has file size = 154 KB. I have to say that when you see the two image, all of the human-being would say it is the same, but in terms of binary bits, there are different in something that I would like to know.

Maybe some of you will say it doesn't matter, as long as image is the same when you look at it. In fact, during the processing of some noise project, this is a huge problem, and I suspect that this is the reason why I have the problem.

I just want to know if there are other method than `BufferedImage` to produce `int[][]` and then to create the output?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
public int[][] Read_Image(BufferedImage image)
{
  width = image.getWidth();
  height = image.getHeight();
  int[][] result = new int[height][width];
  for (int row = 0; row < height; row++)
     for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) 
        result[row][col] = image.getRGB(row, col);
  return result;
}

public BufferedImage Create_Gray_Image(int [][] pixels)
{
    BufferedImage Ima = new BufferedImage(512,512, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    for (int x = 0; x < 512; x++) 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 512; y++) 
        {
            int rgb = pixels[x][y];
            int r = (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
            int g = (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
            int b = (rgb & 0xFF);

            int grayLevel = (r + g + b) / 3;
            int gray = (grayLevel << 16) + (grayLevel << 8) + grayLevel; 
            Ima.setRGB(x, y, pixels[x][y]);
        }
    }
    return Ima;
}

 public void Write_Image(int [][] pixels) throws IOException
{
    File outputfile;
    outputfile = new File("Y0111.png");
    BufferedImage BI = this.Create_Gray_Image(pixels);
    ImageIO.write(BI, "png", outputfile);
    System.out.println("We finished writing the file");
}
```

See the figure, you see file size = 176 KB (this is the original image) and file size = 154 KB (this is the output image).

[image]

Comment: This will most likely come down to the image format and the compression level used when writing the image

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good point, do you know any other writing format that makes compression the same as the input one?

Comment: I'd start by writing out the original BufferedImage directly to see if that makes any difference. The other difference might be the color model used by the original image

Comment: What format is the input image?

Comment: Even if both images were PNG, it's still possible for gray PNGs to be stored as gray, (gray + A), indexed, RGB or RGBA with the exact same pixel values. And even if the color model is the same, PNG has various options controlling compression (fast compression/larger size, slower compression/smaller size) and interlacing options. Files can also contain comments and meta data. So unless you write both files yourself, having the exact same bits (or even file size) is next to impossible.

Comment: @weston sorry for not responding earlier, the format is PNG format and also the output is on the PNG format.

Comment: Another reason they might be different is meta data. Try opening the files in a text editor, you may see a large meta data Xml block in the original the will not be copied to the new image. That could easily account for 22K I'd have thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference of size is not a problem. It's certainly because of different compression/encoding.

A BufferedImage is in fact a 1D array of size width * height * channel. getRGB is not the easiest/fastest way to manipulate a BufferedImage. You can use the Raster (faster than getRGB, not the fastest, but it takes care of the encoding for you). For a gray level image:

```
int[][] my array = new int[myimage.getHeight()][myimage.getWidth()] ;
for (int y=0 ; y < myimage.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < myimage.getWidth() ; x++)
        myarray[y][x] = myimage.getRaster().getSample(x, y, 0) ;
```

The opposite way:

```
for (int y=0 ; y < myimage.getHeight() ; y++)
    for (int x=0 ; x < myimage.getWidth() ; x++)
        myimage.getRaster().setSample(x, y, 0, myarray[y][x]) ;
```

The fastest way to do it is to use the DataBuffer, but then you have to handle the image encoding.

Comment: Amazing, Yes, this is what I'm looking for, Thank you so so much .. I tested and it works and outputs size is the same as the input size ..

Comment: Glad it works for you. But as I said, the difference of size is certainly from an other issue. If you want to have to fastest transformation, use the DataBuffer, else the raster is fine.